# Writing EXIF data from a byte array in Android

Tags: java, android, exif

I am writing a camera app for Android in Java. Having met with the rotation issue that needed me to obtain the orientation from the Exif data, I was wondering if there is a way to add my own tags.

I found the `ExifInterface` class provided in the SDK, starting from the version 24.

The way I'm creating an object:

```
ExifInterface exific = new ExifInterface(new ByteArrayInputStream(jpeg));
```

The `jpeg` object is of the type `byte[]` passed to the `Camera.PictureCallback`'s `onPictureTaken` callback.

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html), there is a method `setAttribute` that I tried to use this way:

```
exific.setAttribute("MY_OWN_TAG", "somevalue");
```

I also tried with one of the tags that are provided:

```
exific.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ARTIST, "myself");
```

Afterward (in another method), I tried reading the tag:

```
try{
    ExifInterface exific = new ExifInterface(new ByteArrayInputStream(jpeg));
    String rv = exific.getAttribute(tag);
    Log.d(TAG, "Obtained value for tag " + tag + ": " + rv);
    return rv;
} catch(IOException ioe){
    Log.d(TAG, "Exif interface query failed.");
}
```

The logged value is null.

A few things come to mind:

- I would say the issue is that I'm constructing the object using a `ByteArrayInputStream`? It seems to me that the `setAttribute` is silently failing because the stream is input only. Alas, I see no other way to create an object using a byte array.
- I will try to do the same thing using a file, just for testing purposes, but the nature of my application would be better suited if I manipulated the byte array.

So, is there a way to write to Exif data using a byte array?